# NSCollectionView doesn't seem to need registering its item class

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

When I made NSCollectionView UI...

First time, I registered my collection view item class using

```
self.cv.register(NSNib.init(nibNamed: "ContentItemOneClass", bundle: nil), forItemWithIdentifier: "ContentItemOneClass")
```

and I added more collection views and forget to call like

```
self.cv.register(NSNib.init(nibNamed: "ContentItemTwoClass", bundle: nil), forItemWithIdentifier: "ContentItemTwoClass")
```

but `collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)` , `makeItem(withIdentifier:"ContentItemTwoClass", for: indexPath)` seems to work just fine.

Now I wonder if registering classes is necessary or can be removed.

thanks.

Comment: Provided that your collection view item xib file knows what the corresponding collection view item swift file is, the answer is no.

Comment: I removed all register codes and my app still works fine. I guess if xib file name is same as class file (or name) than register code is maybe not necessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a sample application called [`CocoaSlideCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CocoaSlideCollection/Introduction/Intro.html) that demonstrates the use of the modern (i.e. 10.11+) `NSCollectionView`. In the `collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` method in the file `AAPLBrowserWindowController.m`, there is this comment:

> Message back to the collectionView, asking it to make a @"Slide" item associated with the given item indexPath.  The collectionView will first check whether an NSNib or item Class has been registered with that name (via -registerNib:forItemWithIdentifier: or -registerClass:forItemWithIdentifier:).  Failing that, the collectionView will search for a .nib file named "Slide".  Since our .nib file is named "Slide.nib", no registration is necessary.

While I didn't see this explicitly mentioned in the documentation, this suggests that as long as the `.xib` name matches the identifier (and has one and only one `NSCollectionViewItem` or subclass of in the file), then registration isn't needed.

Comment: That sounds like if i use registration I may have little bit of performance benefit. However I rather choose simple way writing my code than the benefit. Thanks~